# xsd import from different project, generate java class

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have two projects, A and B. In project A I have common.xsd file where I use cxf-xjc-plugin
  to generate java classes which work good. Next, I want to reuse this created files and type difinitions from common.xsd
  in main.xsd file in project B and don't generate classes from project A again, but there is a problem, because I can't
  include full path in my main.xsd file

```
 <xs:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="PATH_TO_PROJECT_A/common.xsd" />
```

or you classpath
  I read that it is possible to use http, but I can't use it. Is there a way to use a maven or something to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, keywords are:

- [Separate schema compilation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation) with episodes to avoid generating classes which are already generated
- [Catalogs](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Usingcatalogs) to override schema location including pointing to the schema inside the Maven artifact

Required disclaimer: I'm the author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` which provides these features.

Update:

> I tried to use separate schema compilation, but unfortunately I can't
>   undersant it. Should I create separate jar only for xsd file and use
>   it as a dependency ? Now I have dependency to the whole project A
>   which contains generated classes and xsd file

This is enough. You need a JAR with generated classes, XSD files and `META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode`. All of this is normally generated by default.

Then you can use this JAR as an "episode". XJC will use `sun-jaxb.episode` resource as binding file automatically, and this file basically says something like "don't generate anything for the schema in namespace X, use the following classes instead." This is one part which allows you to avoid redundant generation of classes. This works *mostly*, but sometimes XJC still generates a few things - they can be safely deleted.

The other thing is that you want to use schemas from the JAR. This can be done with catalogs and a special entity resolver which is by default delivered by the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

So just use any `schemaLocation` and then rewrite it in the catalog file:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM
 "https://acme.com/foo/a.xsd"
 "maven:com.acme.foo:foo-a!/a.xsd"
```

Comment: I tried to use separate schema compilation, but unfortunately I can't undersant it. Should I create separate jar only for xsd file and use it as a dependency ? Now I have
            dependency to the whole project A which contains generated classes and xsd file

Comment: I click on common.xsd in eclipse to generate jaxb classes and I have it, but I don't have in this project this episod file

Comment: Well, then you probably can't solve it with pure Eclipse. See if there is a setting to include `-episode` argument there.

Comment: Thank you, generating class work good, but I still don't have access to simple type definitions from common.xsd file in my main.xsd in project B.
Could you explain in more detail how to do it? I would like to not use http.Is it possible ? I use maven

Comment: Yes. Just write any URL like https://acme.com/foo/a.xsd and use a catalog to point it to maven:com.acme.foo:foo-a!/a.xsd. Catalog + entity resolver will get your schema from JAR then, no HTTP requests.

Comment: but as I wrote I don't want to use http and upload my xsd file, because I can't do this. I found
   this https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/episodes/d/src/main/resources/catalog.cat
   and I tried to implement this, but I still get null pointer because types declared in common.xsd are
   invisible

Comment: Should this catalog has extension .cat or may it be txt?

Comment: If you rewrite the URL using the catalog file, you don't need to upload anything. Catalog file may have any extension as long as you configure it in the POM: https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/episodes/d/pom.xml

Comment: I have REWRITE_SYSTEM "https://tmp/common.xsd" "maven:groupId_of_projectA:artifact_of_projectA!/common.xsd"
in my src/main/resources/catalog.txt in project B

and  <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.txt</catalog> in project B pom.xml

How should look like import in my main.xsd . I tried <xs:import namespace="https://tmp/S4A_Commons-2.0.xsd"/>
but doesn't work

Comment: Please check the https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/episodes/, it is a fully working example. If you use REWRITE_SYSTEM you have to specify the same URL in REWRITE_SYSTEM and in the schemaLocation of the import. You specify different URLs and use namespace instead of schemaLocation, no wonder it does not work.

Comment: See this example of schema: https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/episodes/b/src/main/resources/b.xsd and this example of catalog: https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/episodes/b/src/main/resources/catalog.cat.

Comment: I got nullpointer : Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: maven-jaxb2-plugin.dev.java.net

Comment: The highsource.org and java.net links do not seem to be working at this time.  I found https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs which may be more current and links to https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Sample-Project-Using-Catalog